# What is the grassy-looking plant at the base of my blueberry bush?

Tags: weeds, blueberries

I bought a starter blueberry bush a couple of months ago.  It has been growing well but there seems to be something else growing at the base. I'm not sure if it's more blueberry stalk or weeds, and I'm hoping someone can help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's weeds, it is some kind of grass. Seedlings of blueberries look more like [this](http://prima-blueberry.com/en/produkts/) (first picture).

You can pull the weeds out of there, they compete with nutrients available in the soil.

Answer (score 5):

These are not blueberry stalks for sure.

This is probably one of the [*Panicum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panicum) plant like [**Common Millet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proso_millet).

You may wait the first seeds to show up to be sure. It will not be long.

Answer (score 4):

In Illinois or Texas in the United States, that would be clearly crabgrass.